# CSS Grid auto-flow dense only changes flow of narrow elements

Tags: html, css, css-grid

My grid has `1fr` and `3fr` wide elements. Both elements have the same height.

This is how the grid looks with normal row flow:

[image: Without grid-auto-flow: dense]

This is how grid looks with "**grid-auto-flow: dense**":

[image: With grid-auto-flow: dense]

As you can observe, the last narrow element moves upwards to fill the gap, but still leaves a gap before the 3fr cell.

This is how I would expect the "grid-auto-flow: dense" to work:

[image: Hypothetical grid-auto-flow: dense behavior]

Is there any way to make the `grid-auto-flow: dense` reflow wide elements to **completely avoid gaps?**

Thank you.

Comment: CSS grid cannot do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid can't change order of element than way. As a solution I can suggest a little trick. Lats agree that our `3fr` element will always be the last one in query. So at that point we could add to it some simple check using `:nth-child()`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.grid>div {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1; /* starts form the fist  row gap*/
}

.three:nth-child(4),
.three:nth-child(5),
.three:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.three:nth-child(7),
.three:nth-child(8),
.three:nth-child(9),
.three:nth-child(n+9) /* for any element position > 9 */ {
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>      
  
  <div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, very nice trick! I have to adapt it a bit, but I think SCSS functions will come in very handy. Thank you again!